# How to name columns for multi mapping support in Dapper?

Tags: c#, dapper

```
var sql = @"SELECT
    a.id AS `Id`, 
    a.thing AS `Name`, 
    b.id AS `CategoryId`,
    b.something AS `CategoryName`  
FROM ..";

var products = connection.Query<Product, Category, Product>(sql,
    (product, category) =>
    {
        product.Category = category;
        return product;
    }, 
    splitOn: "CategoryId");

foreach(var p in products)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0} (#{1}) in {2} (#{3})", p.Name, p.Id, p.Category.Name, p.Category.Id);
}
```

Results in:

```
'First (#1) in  (#0)'
'Second (#2) in  (#0)'
```

CategoryId and CategoryName has values since the following

```
var products = connection.Query(sql).Select<dynamic, Product>(x => new Product
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Name = x.Name,
    Category = new Category { Id = x.CategoryId, Name = x.CategoryName }
});
```

Results in:

```
'First (#1) in My Category (#10)'
'Second (#2) in My Category (#10)'
```

I'm connecting to a MySQL database if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: you are using spliton properly there, do you mind submitting a broken test to the tracker in google code?

Comment: @Sam I'm guessing it should have worked if I had changed `'CategoryName'` to just `'Name'`? I was under the impression that Dapper would use some automapper convention to map `'CategoryName'` (also tried `'Category.Name'`) to `x.Category.Name`

Comment: yeah you are right @loraderon, it does not append Category to all the props ... in fact its simpler just to handle duplicate column names in the result set. then you can do stuff like `select * from Posts p join Authors a on p.AuthorId = a.Id` which is so succinct

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way is to call them all `Id` (case-insensitive, so just `a.id` and `b.id` are fine); then you can use:

```
    public void TestMultiMapWithSplit()
    {
        var sql = @"select 1 as Id, 'abc' as Name, 2 as Id, 'def' as Name";
        var product = connection.Query<Product, Category, Product>(sql,
           (prod, cat) =>
           {
               prod.Category = cat;
               return prod;
           }).First();
        // assertions
        product.Id.IsEqualTo(1);
        product.Name.IsEqualTo("abc");
        product.Category.Id.IsEqualTo(2);
        product.Category.Name.IsEqualTo("def");
    }
```

If you can't do that, there is an optional `splitOn` (`string`) parameter that takes a comma-separated list of columns to treat at splits.

Comment: Never thought it would be that easy! Thanks!

Comment: @loraderon we're exceptionally lazy, and we write things that are easy to use ;p